# Question about IF statement's condition and how to make it work

Tags: c++

So I was working on an IF statement where

```
if (((number_one > 10) + (number_two < -10)) == 5) {
    printf("%d + %d = five", number_one, number_two);
```

I basically wanted the code to recognise that if the user inputted the first number (number_one) and it met the condition that it was greater than 10, and the second number (number_two) was less than -10, then when both numbers are added together and equals to 5, the if condition is fulfilled and the printf statement will happen.
The issue is, this doesn't work due to "== 5" as when I remove the "== 5", the condition works with my program and when it's there, it doesn't. Can anyone provide suggestions or workarounds?
I'm a beginner and I only know of printf, scanf, if/else if/else statements so using those would be preferred. Thank you!

Comment: fwiw, in C++ `prinf` and `scanf` are advanced. Simple C++ i/o is `std::cin` and `std::cout`

Answer (score 2):

Let's brake this line which you wrote here (we are going from in to out):

```
(((number_one > 10) + (number_two < -10)) == 5)

  (number_one > 10) => this evaluates to true or false, which means true == 1 and false == 0

                      (number_two < -10) => the same as the first
```

So you are either adding

```
0+0 
0+1 
1+0 
1+1
```

which will never evaluate to 5

Look at @Jarod42's answer how to implement the conditions correctly

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&` or [`and`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and):

```
if ((number_one > 10) && (number_two < -10) && (number_one + number_two  == 5)) {
  /*..*/
}
```